# I am trying to replace One screen with another in my chat app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a web based chat application, and instead of using a full browser window, I am trying to replicate Linkedin chat UI at the footer, But I am using one view, such that , the first view `MessageList Component` displays the list of messaged users and when I click on a user, it replaces this screen at the footer with that `MessageChat Component`, where I can write the messages, and when I click on the back arrow on this, it goes back to the `MessageList Component`

Heres some of my code snippet

THis is my message list Component

```
const MessageList = () => {
  const history = useHistory()

  const { search } = useLocation()
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }))
  const socket = useRef()

  const [chats, setChats] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)


  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllChats = async (token) => {
      try {
        setLoading(true)
        const res = await getChats(token)
        if (res) {
          setChats(res)
          setLoading(false)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }

    getAllChats(user.token)
  }, [user])

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
      <MessageBanner />
      <div style={{ overflowY: 'scroll', height: 500 }}>
        {chats.length > 0
          ? chats.map((chat, i) => (
              <UserCard
                chat={chat}
                key={i}
                onClick={() => console.log(chat.messagesWith)}
              />
            ))
          : 'No Chat'}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

On Click, I want to replace this component with this component, passing the `chat.messagesWith`

I want to pass the data to this `MessageChat Component`

```
const MessageChat = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
      <MessageChatBanner />
      <div style={{ overflowY: 'scroll', height: 500, paddingBottom: 180 }}>
        <Sender />
        <Receiver />
        <Receiver />
        <Sender />
        {/* <Receiver />
        <Sender />
        <Sender /> */}
      </div>
      <MessageInput />
    </div>
  )
}

export default MessageChat
```

THis is the Main Compoment that should hold and both the MessageChat and MessageList Component

```
const ShowMessage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { chatApp, user } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }))

  return (
    <>
      {!chatApp && (
        <div>
          {/* <MessageChat /> */}
          <MessageList />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default ShowMessage
```

PS: I dont know if `react-router-dom` works here, since I am not passing the data from the URL

Comment: `react-router-dom` or any routing code for that matter doesn't appear to be very relevant here. This is all code you are running in the footer, right? So I've gathered you want to swap between rendering the `MessageList` and `MessageChat` components chatting with a specific user. I this correct? Can you share the code running in the footer that would handle swapping between the two?

Comment: Yes, It is running in the footer. And you are correct, I want to render between both `MessageList` and `MessageChat` inside the `ShowMessage` which is the main code at the footer. I removed the CSS code since its irrelevant to this. These are all the codes I have. The swapping should happen in the `ShowMessage` Component. I really don't know how to swap between them.